# A quote from Lotze's Methaphysik. Is he putting forth the same idea of Nietzsche's Ubermensch?

Tags: nietzsche

Lotze in his book Metaphysik, article 245, writes on immortality as follows

> We have no other principle for deciding it than this general idealistic belief : that every created thing will continue whose continuance belongs to the meaning of the world, and so long as it does so belong ; whilst every one will pass away whose reality is justified only in a transitory phase of the world's course. That this principle admits of no further application in human hands need hardly be said. We surely know not the merits which may give to one being a claim on eternity, nor the defects which would cut others off.

I mean, it seems, when he says that those who only contribute in transitioning will pass away, very much aligned to Nietzasche's "Man is only a bridge to Superman". Did he have the same idea, rather inchoate though, of Ubermensch that Nietzsche developed more concretely?